# withContext after a CoroutineScope.launch - will CoroutineScope.launch block?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I just stumbled over this code:

```
fun addHeaderAndSubmitList(list: List<SleepNight>?) {
    adapterScope.launch {
        val items = when (list) {
            null -> listOf(DataItem.Header)
            else -> listOf(DataItem.Header) + list.map { DataItem.SleepNightItem(it) }
        }
        // isn't there any code required to wait for the
        // adapterScope.launch coroutine to finish?
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            submitList(items)
        }
    }
}
```

found in [this file of the google sleeptracker](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-with-recyclerview/blob/Step.09-Solution-Add-Binding-Adapters/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt) example.

I already added my question as comment in the code example. I am new to coroutines but to my knowledge `adapterScope.launch` is non-blocking, so `adapterScope.launch` might not be finished until

```
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        submitList(items)
    }
```

is reached? Am I wrong about this? If not, how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what the problem is? Where are you stuck? If the question is only the comment you added then The Answer is NO. I will provide an explanation if it is a question

Comment: yes, it's only the comment that is the question. always thought coroutines run non-blocking and if i want them to run blocking, then there is `runBlocking` for it.

Comment: oh, I got it. I mixed up the `}` ending `launch` and `val items[..]`. my fault ):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html).

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread [...]

Here's what happens:

1. `addHeaderAndSubmitList` uses `launch` to start some *asynchronous* work. The work will finish naturally or will be terminated when `adapterScope`'s lifecycle ends. Meanwhile `addHeaderAndSubmitList` finishes immediately.
2. Whatever is inside `launch {}` runs *sequentially*. `submitList(items)` is called after `val items = ...`. Each happens effectively on a different thread, but the order is guaranteed.

Comment: both answers are correct, but it made "click" when I read this answer because it explicitely states that `addHeaderAndSubmitList ` uses `launch`. The entire method body is part of the coroutine, this is where my mistake was because I mixed up two `}`

Answer (score 0):

The code inside launch { } runs sequentially in a blocking fashion inside the adapterScope, meaning all the code above the withContext(Main) is run and finished before switching contexts to submit the list to the adapter on the main thread.

The entire code block is likely running in an Default or IO context, so it runs in a blocking fashion outside the main thread, until it reaches the withContext(Main) to post the results to the main thread.